# Просуммировать каждый участок кода, который был преобразован из строчного типа

Tags: java

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой написания метода, который бы смог сложить подстроки, которые преобразованы в числовой тип, содержащие значение Unicode.

Вот часть моего кода:

```
public class Action {

static public void codesSum () {
    
    String s = "admin coming home";
    String[] words = s.split("\\s");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    for(String subStr : words) {
            
       for(char ch : subStr.toCharArray()) {
          sb.append((int)ch);
           BigInteger mInt = new BigInteger(sb.toString());
           System.out.println(mInt);

        }
    
}
}
}
```

Для полного понимания вот само задание:

**Подсчитать суммы кодов символов лексем во введенном предложении и проверить, является ли полученный числовой ряд
невозрастающей последовательностью.**

Буду очень благодарен за любую подсказку!)

Comment: Вам нужно подсчитать суммы кодов символов, но вы складываете символы в stringBuilder и пытаетесь преобразовать строку в BigInteger, зачем?

Comment: Данную часть кода позаимствовал на форуме, где разбиралось преобразование всей строки в тип числа Unicode, а не отдельного символа, как сделать иначе в таком случае, не могу догадаться.

Comment: просто везде разбираются вопросы о переводе единичного элемента, а как целое предложение перевести, это совсем другое

Comment: Как я понял, нужно разбить предложение на лексемы и просуммировать все коды символов в каждой лексеме, не понимаю, зачем преобразовывать всю строку в последовательность кодов.

Comment: Потому что данную последовательность необходимо будет проанализировать с условием, статичная она или нет. 
То-есть иными словами тут 2 подзадания,: 1) просуммировать, 2) выявить саму последовательность, как я понял.

Comment: А разбил я её, потому что сама последовательность получается слипшаяся, да и учитель мне объяснил, что необходимо в начале самом разбить предложение на слова

Comment: Тут разве не нужно сформировать последовательность из сумм кодов символов лексем?

Comment: То-есть сначала мне необходимо получить числовой код данного предложения, потом просуммировать каждое отдельное слово и составить из этого уже последовательность?

Comment: Разбить на слова, сложить символы в каждом слове, но не в StringBuilder, а в int, и проверить, что вычисленная сумма меньше или равна предыдущей

Comment: Просто я не понимаю, как мне тогда сложить коды каждой буквы в слово(в одну переменную), а после этого сформировать последовательность, везде перешарил, нигде подобное не упоминается

Comment: сложить нужно не в слово, вам нужна сумма: (int) 'a' + (int) 'b' и тд

Comment: да, я исправился,  могли бы вы на примере показать данный алгоритм, если вас не затруднит?

Comment: Существует же метод, который сможет всё это более компактно сделать?

Comment: можно придумать какой-нибудь однострочник, но он будет выполнять те же самые действия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static public void codesSum () {

String s = "admin coming home";
String[] words = s.split(" ");
int prevSum = -1;

for(String word : words) {
   int sum = 0;     
   for(char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
       sum += (int) ch;
    }
if (prevSum != -1){
    if (prevSum < sum){
        // поледовательность не неубывающая
        return;
    }
prevSum = sum;

}
// поледовательность неубывающая
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, я ещё подумывал может попытаться собрать данные числа в коллекцию, а потом просуммировать их с помощью List

Comment: не проще ли будет сравнить каждые 2 соседних символа в строке вместо того, чтобы считать суммы? `for(i=1; i<word.len; i++) if (word[i] < word[i-1]) {  не неубывающая }`

Comment: вроде там нужно сравнивать суммы кодов слов

Comment: Вот такое вот задание, ничто не поделаешь)

Comment: а, да, отмена операции, я кажется задание по диагонали прочитал )

Comment: ну кто то по диагонали читает, а кто-то по диагонали и в совершенно противоположном направлении мыслит, что в моём случае уместно)

Comment: мне кажется, во внутреннем цикле должно быть только это `sum += (int) ch;` - остальное вынести после внутреннего цикла,  - вот это меня смутило, в коде.

Comment: вы правы, исправил

Comment: @tewboat у меня выходит теперь неясная ошибка во внутреннем цикле (word): Итерация возможна только по массиву или экземпляру java.lang.Iterable. 
не понимаю почему он ругается, ведь даже если я его объявлю экземпляром в классе, то ошибка не исчезает, с чем может быть связано?

Comment: Попытался поработать с `[Symbol.iterator]() {}` , но ошибок стало ещё больше, может ли он как-нибудь решить эту проблему?

Comment: можно вызвать метод toCharArray() у word или пройтись обычным for

Comment: @tewboat так у нас же объявляется переменная words уже как массив, соответственно и метод данный не подойдёт, его нужно добавить во внутреннем цикле.
А извиняюсь, прочитал ещё раз, вы так и написали